# Azure Storage Type Provider: FS0039 on build but intellisense shows type as available

Tags: azure, f#, azure-storage, type-providers

I am trying to access a type from our Azure Storage account using the [Azure Storage Type Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/AzureStorageTypeProvider):

```
type AzAcc = AzureTypeProvider<"{our ac name}","{our key}">
type clientEntity = AzAcc.Domain.FeedLabClientsEntity
```

I get intellisense for the `FeedLabClientsEntity` type and can proceed without the Visual Studio 'red squiggly' but on build the second line above throws the error

```
error FS0039: The type 'FeedLabClientsEntity' is not defined
```

How can I access this type?

Comment: There was an approved edit with the removal of the windows-azure-storage tag and a comment stating that the type provider was not supported by Microsoft. Whilst acknowledging that the Type Provider is unsupported, I believe the use of the tag is still relevant and appropriate to my question which is about a TP that specifically targets azure storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is a "feature" of the TP. Unlike most other TPs which eagerly evaluate schema and generate the type system up front, the Azure TP generates types on demand, so only once you navigate through blobs or tables do those types appear accessible. It most mostly due to save on potential IO - if you point to a real Azure account, theoretically you could have an infinite number of tables and blobs.

You can work around this by first trying to access the appropriate table using e.g. GetPartition.

Comment: Now fixed in 1.5 :-)